# Change 3 dots of secondary toolbar to an icon in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to replace the default '3 dots'(that displays the secondary items) to text or icon on the title bar of a page in xamarin forms.
Is this possible and how can I achieve this?

Thank you for the responses in advance.

Answer (score -1):

**Making sure to add the method that will handle the Activated event in C#.**

In XAML, before the opening tag of your ContentPage.Content, add the code below.

**From dots to Text**

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Hi" Clicked="Clicked_1"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Hello" Clicked="Clicked_2"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

**From dots to Icon**

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="icon.png" Activated="Clicked_3" Text="Icon" Order="Primary"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: This works only to replace the dots, but does not allow children to be added to the menu.