# How do I hide the default toolbar button (three dots) in Xamarin.Forms UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, toolbar

I have a Xamarin.Forms UWP app with a `<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>` defined with two toolbarItems.
In UWP this toolbar renders but displays an extra (or default) button with 3 dots that expands but does not contain any buttons. I want to remove this extra button.

I found some references on this problem but they didn't work for me:

- [Change 3 dots of secondary toolbar to an icon in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50800636/change-3-dots-of-secondary-toolbar-to-an-icon-in-xamarin-forms)
- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70814/how-to-remove-ellipsis-button-in-navigation-bar-for-uwp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the answer in the link that you mentioned in your post, did you tried to put below code in your App.Xaml of your UWP project:

```
<Application.Resources>
   <x:Double x:Key="AppBarExpandButtonThemeWidth">0</x:Double>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I tried this but maybe I put it in the wrong App.Xaml. With your hint it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows 10 Anniversary Edition ( so your project's min version is 14393 and target version is 14393 or greater ) there is a property on the CommandBar that you can use to toggle the visibility of the 3 dots/more button.

It's call OverflowButtonVisibilty and the docs are here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.overflowbuttonvisibility

You can set it like so

```
<CommandBar OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed"></CommandBar>
```

Comment: this answer does not apply to my scenario because the toolbaritems are defined on my shared xamarin project and not in my uwp project

Comment: True, but you can still set that property as a style in the UWP project app.xaml so that it will be triggered there

Comment: @Depechie : Can you add the line to your answer that sets the property in the `app.xaml`?

Comment: @Christian not sure what you are asking? Do you want an example of setting this as a style you mean?

Comment: @Depechie the style in which [Dishant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53147473/25282) does.